# Change part of image src/dataimage attribute on particular active div

Tags: jquery, slider

Thanks for dropping by and taking your time to read this. Much appreciated.

For our website we have a slider showing the package from the products. The slider works as follows:

- You can currently select a colour and the package-image will update and show the selected color. The image src in .header-module-images will be updated with the DATA-IMAGE attribute from active span from .header-module-swatches.
- Also the color name is displayed below in the corresponding color. The span from i.product-code will be updated with the DATA-PRODUCTCODE attribute and gets the right color from the DATA-PRODUCTCOLOR attribute.

For a particular product we have different colors, but also different sizes/lengths. Currently the slider has a div showing the two different sizes with corresponding prices.

**Code:**

```
<div class="header-module-images">
    <img alt="Packaging" src="/wp-content/uploads/abcd150ru-packaging.png">
</div>

<section class="header-module-swatches">
    <span class="" data-image="/wp-content/uploads/abcd150cl-packaging.png" data-index="0" data-productcode="Cloud" data-productcolor="#dbd9d4" style="background-color: #dbd9d4;"></span> 
    <span class="" data-image="/wp-content/uploads/abcd150bc-packaging.png" data-index="1" data-productcode="Buttercup" data-productcolor="#fbeeb4" style="background-color: #fbeeb4;"></span> 
    <span class="" data-image="/wp-content/uploads/abcd150pt-packaging.png" data-index="2" data-productcode="Peppermint" data-productcolor="#97e0d7" style="background-color: #97e0d7;"></span> 
    <span class="" data-image="/wp-content/uploads/abcd150cu-packaging.png" data-index="3" data-productcode="Cupcake" data-productcolor="#f8d6cf" style="background-color: #f8d6cf;"></span> 
    <span class="" data-image="/wp-content/uploads/abcd150ar-packaging.png" data-index="4" data-productcode="Army" data-productcolor="#69693f" style="background-color: #69693f;"></span> 
    <span class="" data-image="/wp-content/uploads/abcd150in-packaging.png" data-index="5" data-productcode="Indigo" data-productcolor="#065b85" style="background-color: #065b85;"></span> 
    <span class="active" data-image="/wp-content/uploads/abcd150ru-packaging.png" data-index="6" data-productcode="Ruby" data-productcolor="#872d39" style="background-color: #872d39;"></span>
    <span class="" data-image="/wp-content/uploads/abcd150cc-packaging.png" data-index="7" data-productcode="Concrete" data-productcolor="#4c4c4c" style="background-color: #4c4c4c;"></span> 
        <i class="product-code">
            <span style="color: #872d39;">Ruby</span>
        </i>
</section>

<div class="product-header-variations">
    <span class="active" data-index="0" data-productcode="1.5m" data-productprice="€ 14.99">1.5m</span> 
    <span class="" data-index="1" data-productcode="3m" data-productprice="€ 24.99">3m</span> 
        <i class="product-price">
            <span style="">€ 14.99</span>
        </i>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
initVariationPackagingCarousel: function() {

        $('#product-packaging-container .product-header-variations').on('mouseenter', 'span[data-productprice]:not(.active)', function(){

            var that = $(this)

            // Change active price   
            that.siblings().removeClass('active');
            that.addClass('active');

            // Change active productcode   
            $('#product-packaging-container .product-header-variations .product-price > span').text(that.data('productprice'));    
        });
    },


initPackagingSwatchesCarousel: function() {

        var $img = $('#product-packaging-container .header-module-images img'),
                dsrc = $img.attr('src');
              $('#product-packaging-container .header-module-swatches span').hover(function() {
                var $this = $(this);
                setTimeout(function(){ $img.attr('src', $this.data('image'));}, 300);
              });

        $('#product-packaging-container .header-module-swatches').on('mouseenter', 'span[data-productcode]:not(.active)', function(){

            var that = $(this),
                carousel = $('#product-packaging-container .header-module-images');

            // Change active thumb   
            that.siblings().removeClass('active');
            that.addClass('active');

            // Change active productcode   
            $('#product-packaging-container .header-module-swatches .product-code > span').text(that.data('productcode'));
            $('#product-packaging-container .header-module-swatches .product-color > span').text(that.data('productcolor'));

            // Change colour text colour
            $('#product-packaging-container .header-module-swatches i.product-code span').css('color','' + that.data('productcolor') + '');
            $('#product-packaging-container .header-module-images img').addClass("fadeOut").delay(400).queue(function(next){
                  $(this).removeClass("fadeOut");
                  next();
              });
        });     
    },
```

**Goal:**

I want to make it so that when a particular size is selected, a part of the price image src in .header-module-images **AND** data-image attribute in .header-module-swatches is updated, only replacing 150 with 300. **So:**

```
 <img alt="Packaging" src="/wp-content/uploads/abcd150ru-packaging.png">
```

will be come

```
 <img alt="Packaging" src="/wp-content/uploads/abcd300ru-packaging.png">
```

and

```
<span class="" data-image="/wp-content/uploads/abcd150cl-packaging.png">
```

will be come

```
<span class="" data-image="/wp-content/uploads/abcd300cl-packaging.png">
```

Who can push me in the right direction?

Easiest would be to update data-productcode within .product-header-variations to "150"/"300" and when a .product-header-variations span is active, within #product-packaging-container "150" is replaced with active data-productcode "300" and vice versa.